# Django testing: AssertionError: The form 'form' was not used to render the response

Tags: python, django, forms, testing

So I'm writing a test to check for the occurrence of Validation Errors in my Form.

In doing so I'm getting the following error:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_start_date_before_end_date_errors (reports.tests.ScheduleValidation)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jwe/piesup2/reports/tests.py", line 61, in test_start_date_before_end_date_errors
    self.assertFormError(response, 'form', None, 'End Date Must Be Greater Than Start Date')
  File "/home/jwe/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 467, in assertFormError
    " response" % form)
AssertionError: The form 'form' was not used to render the response

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The validation error I'm specifically checking for is raised in models.py inside the `clean()` method

```
class Schedule(models.Model)
    ... 
    ...

    def clean(self):
        if self.start_date and self.end_date:
            # Ensure that the end_date occurs after the start_date
            if self.end_date <= self.start_date:
                err = "End Date Must Be Greater Than Start Date"
                raise ValidationError(err)
```

The Generic CreateView I am testing looks as follows:

```
class ScheduleCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, FetchURLMixin, CreateView):
    model = Schedule
    form_class = ScheduleCreateForm
    template_name_suffix = '_create_form'
```

I'm able to render the errors in the view's template as `non_field_errors` as so:

```
{% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
    <label>{{ error }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

My test looks as follows:

```
class ScheduleValidation(RequiresLogin, TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self._client = client_fixture.create()[0]
        # Setup some example sample data for a Schedule
        self.data = {
            'client': self._client.id,
            'schedule_date': today,
            'billing_period': 'Q',
            'schedule_type': 'SE',

        }

    def test_start_date_before_end_date_errors(self):
        self.data['start_date'] = today
        self.data['end_date'] = yesterday
        response = self.client.post('reports:schedule-create', self.data, follow=True)
        # Check if redirects back to the page
        with self.assertTemplateUsed('schedule_create_form.html'):
            self.assertFormError(response, 'form', None, 'End Date Must Be Greater Than Start Date')
```

I'm setting the field type of `None` in order to access `non_field_errors` as detailed by the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertFormError)

### What I've Tried Already

Inside my template for the view, I'm able to reference the form using `{{ form }}`, including any `non_field_errors`. Which means it is being passed to the template properly.

I can check the context data inside the view itself.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ScheduleCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    assert False
    return context
```

From the breakpoint here I'm able to log the contents of the context variable with Werkzeug in the browser, which shows that 'form' is actually passed to the template

```
[console ready]
>>> context
{'form': <ScheduleCreateForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(client;schedule_date;start_date;end_date;billing_period;schedule_type)>, 'view': <reports.views.ScheduleCreate object at 0x7f256eb6c908>}
```

Which begs the question why am I getting this error, and how would I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `client.post()`, you should use the actual URL, not the name of the url.

You could either hardcode it, for example:

```
response = self.client.post('/reports/schedules/create/, self.data, follow=True)
```

Or you could reverse the url:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
url = reverse('reports:schedule-create')
response = self.client.post(url, self.data, follow=True)
```